# how to install package via composer?

Tags: drush, theming, composer

I would like to add library to my drupal 7 custom module. Library can be installed via composer, but i can't find a solution for install? How can i install this library? I have installed "composer manager" but i still can't get it running.

Comment: I would love to know the answer of this question too.

Comment: Disagree with the close vote on this.  How to use composer with Drupal is definitely on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get started, add a `composer.json` file to your module.  The only thing you need here is the `require` section that includes your external library.

`Composer manager` is one way to combine all of your dependencies together, but there are other options to get Drupal to load your autoload.php file.  The technique I prefer is to create a project-level `composer.json` file in your Drupal root, and use the module [composer_vendor](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_vendor) to include your autoload.php file.

The easiest way to get started is to use the [composer_generate](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_generate) Drush extension to build your project-level `composer.json` file.

`$ drush dl composer_generate
 $ cd /path/to/drupalroot
 $ drush composer-generate > composer.json
 $ composer install`

Composer-generate will add all of the projects currently used in your Drupal site, plus composer_vendor, so `composer install` should just work for you.  The main magic here is in the custom autoloaders added to the template; take a look at the output to see what was included.

Some caution needs to be used here, of course; the default template will put all of your modules in sites/all/modules/contrib.  You can edit the template prior to running composer install if this isn't what you want.

You'll also have to be careful if you have any modified modules; there are a number of ways to deal with any hacked content, but that's a bit beyond the scope of this one question.

**Update**

If you don't want to run Drush, you can also hand-type your own composer.json file using the project https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project.  This is the template that composer-generate is based on.

Comment: we don't use drush. It is about this lib: https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

Comment: You could install Drush and use it only to download and run the composer_generate tool.  This would be faster than hand-typing your own composer.json file.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson adding on to the main question, how can we load vendor autoload.php for 3rd party api?

Comment: Drupal 8 will load the autoloader for you, so I presume you are asking about Drupal 7. Either use the composer_vendor module I recommend above, or just add the include to your settings.php file.