# Loading third party PHP SDK library from a custom module drupal 7

Tags: files, theming

I am writing a custom drupal module (my first one in my life), and I am trying to load an external library (https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php), and until now I used these methods:

1. Loaded file array in info file

   files[] = spotify-web-api-php/vendor/autoload.php,spotify-web-api-php/src/Request.php,spotify-web-api-php/src/Session.php,spotify-web-api-php/src/SpotifyWebAPI.php,spotify-web-api-php/src/SpotifyWebAPIException.php
2. I made this function based on another answers here (Copied the library in libraries folder)

   function blve_spotify_registry_files_alter (&$files, $modules)
   {
     if (!class_exists('SpotifyWebAPI\Session')) {
       $library_path = function_exists('libraries_get_path') ?
         libraries_get_path('spotify-web-api-php') : 'sites/all/libraries/spotify-web-api-php';

   ```
   $files[$library_path . '/vendor/autoload.php'] = array(
     'module' => 'blve_spotify',
     'weight' => 0,
   );
   ```

   }
   }
3. I used require_once but will only work on one function

None of these methods worked, when I made a function to call all the loaded files any of the methods or files I need are loaded, please help me to made it work with the required php files. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [libraries module](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) to load 3rd party dependencies (easier way), or [composer manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager) to load composer package (better way).

[Here you can find](https://www.drupal.org/node/1342238) some details and examples how to start with libraries module.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
files[] = spotify-web-api-php/vendor/autoload.php,spotify-web-api-php/src/Request.php,spotify-web-api-php/src/Session.php,spotify-web-api-php/src/SpotifyWebAPI.php,spotify-web-api-php/src/SpotifyWebAPIException.php
```

Try:

```
files[] = spotify-web-api-php/vendor/autoload.php
files[] = spotify-web-api-php/src/Request.php
files[] = spotify-web-api-php/src/Session.php
files[] = spotify-web-api-php/src/SpotifyWebAPI.php,
files[] = spotify-web-api-php/src/SpotifyWebAPIException.php
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: I just  tried  and it worked but in your case is better to use composer to load that files, take a look at this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/149598/4362

Answer (score 0):

in Drupal 7 i used to do a quick & dirty way, surely it's not recommended, but perhaps can help you or give you inspiration:

*In the following example i load a class called Carbon*

1. create a function, i.e. : `_get_carbon()`

function _get_carbon() {

```
$carbon_path = function_exists('libraries_get_path') ? libraries_get_path('Carbon') : 'sites/all/libraries/Carbon';
$c = $carbon_path . '/src/Carbon/Carbon.php';
require($c);
$GLOBALS['carbon'] = new Carbon\Carbon();
```

}

2. everytime you need this class, call that function `_get_carbon()`, you'll find the class at `$GLOBALS['carbon']`